# How do I use my BLU M8L 2022 tablet as a phone?

Tags: tablet, telephony, blu

How do I use my BLU M8L 2022 tablet as a phone?

Comment: According to the specs on GsmArena this tablet has no 2G/3//4G/5G hardware included. Therefore the only possibility is via VoIP apps. But that requires you to have a VoIP telephone account somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

[GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/blu_m8l_2022-11368.php) is wrong on the hardware. The BLU M8L has 4G LTE hardware. If it didn't, you wouldn't have a SIM and phone number. It does have the radios, just no phone or text system apps visible. The system apps stay hidden.

If I can figure out how to unhide them long enough to be able to add those apps to the home screen, I will post my results.

P.S. to anyone checking, I believe you could still download the apps TextNow, Pinger, and stuff like that, but use their app with your phone number instead of their VoIP setup. It's not ideal but in a worst-case scenario.

You can alternatively, if you know enough about the process. Open developer settings, and enable OEM unlock. From there you could probably find TWRP Recovery and a LineageOS custom ROM. LineageOS tablet ROMs usually have the GApps for Phone on the home screen anyway as default for AOSP Gapps. I will return with my progress.

Comment: Note that custom ROMs like LineageOS cannot bundle GApps inside the ROM due to licensing. However, users can manually flash GApps separately.

Comment: Yes correct... I should have been a little more clear on that!