# Put SIM card w/service and number that didn't come with Blu M22 tablet

Tags: sms, tablet, sim-card, telephony, blu

Is there any to make Blu M22 a phone?

I put a different SIM card on my tablet with service and a number. I have TextNow on the phone and can make calls and send/receive texts from that number. I just need to be able to receive messages to the number on the SIM card I put in.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Though different model number, possibly related: [How do I use my BLU M8L 2022 tablet as a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/252430/44325) That said, for some reason, I can't find "Blu M22" model number on the internet.