# How can I use my BLU M10L Plus tablet 4G LTE as a phone using the SIM phone number?

Tags: calls, tablet, sim-card, blu

How can I use my BLU M10L Plus tablet 4G LTE as a phone using the SIM phone number? I am unable to find the phone and messaging system on my tablet.

Comment: Is the SIM in there ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Though different model number, possibly related: [How do I use my BLU M8L 2022 tablet as a phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/252430/44325)